# Uniform Boundedness principle for bounded linear maps from Frechet Space into a Banach Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am looking for a proof of the uniform boundedness principle where the domain is a Frechet space, instead of the usual setting of a Banach Space.

This is used in proving the space of tempered distributions is complete but I can't find a proof of it anywhere.

When I try to prove it myself I get stuck on the final part(which uses the scaling property of linear maps).

Does anyone have a proof that they could share?

Comment: Doesn't the standard proof via the Baire category theorem just work?

Comment: The problem the last part relies upon the scaling property of a linear map(pulling out a scaler). I admit I'm not well versed in Frechet spaces though - if I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: HAHAHA, Ok I see. Being stupid I was thinking the norm was of the domain and not the range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be Frechet and $Y$ be locally convex. Let $T_a: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous linear map for each $a\in A$, and let $q: Y \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous semi-norm.

If $\sup \{q(T_a x):a\in A\} <\infty$ $\forall x\in X$ (pointwise bounded), then $x\mapsto \sup \{q(T_a x):a\in A\}$ is a continuous semi-norm (i.e., the set $\{T_a : a\in A\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous/uniformly bounded).

To prove this, let 
$$E_n = \{x\in X: q(T_a x) \le n, \forall a\}$$
By pointwise boundedness, we see that $\cup_n E_n = X$. Since $E_n$ are closed and $X$ is a Baire space, we see that there exists $E_n$ with an interior point $x$. Since $X$ is Frechet, its topology is generated by countable semi-norms $p_k$ and thus there exists $N,r$ such that
$$
x + \bigcap_{k=1}^N \{p_k < r\} \subseteq E_n
$$
Hence,
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^N \{p_k < 2r\} \subseteq E_n -E_n \subseteq E_{2n},
$$
because if $a\in \bigcap_{k=1}^N \{p_k < 2r\} $, then $a=(x+a/2)-(x-a/2)\in E_n-E_n$.
Let
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{k=1}^N p_k (x).
$$
Hence,
$$
0\in \{p < 1\} \subseteq E_{2n}\subseteq \{x: \sup \{q(T_a x):a\in A\} <3n\}.
$$
Since $p$ is continuous, we see that $0$ is an interior point of $\{\sup \{q(T_a x):a\in A\} <3n\} $ and thus $\sup \{q(T_a x):a\in A\}$ is a continuous semi-norm.

Comment: I verified the proof and found not a single error. Moreover, an equivalent theorem (for general barreled spaces) is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Generalisations
"Given a barrelled space X and a locally convex space Y, then any family of pointwise bounded continuous linear mappings from X to Y is equicontinuous (even uniformly equicontinuous)." Every Fréchet space is barreled: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space

Comment: {\em Uniformly equicontinuous} means: For every a neighborhood $W\subset Y$ of $0$, there exists a neighborhood $V\subset X$ of $0$ such that $T_a V\subset W$ $\forall a\in A$. It is roughly stated here (the text is vague): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity and exactly in some textbooks.

Comment: An even more general statement is here (some of which could be obtained from Yuan's proof): https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Banach-Steinhaus_theorem
Note that in TVSs, equicontinuity at some $x\in X$ is equivalent to uniform equicontinuity:
If for each $W$ exists $V$ (neighborhoods of $0$) such that $T_a(x+V)\subset T_a x + W$, then $T_a V\subset W$.